# IIS Application name in NLog.config

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7.5, nlog

I am integrating NLog logging in a WCF service hosted in IIS 7.5. Multiple instances (different versions) of the service are installed under the same site, so I would like the Application name to be part of the logging path.

I am aware of the NLog.Web extension and the `${iis-site-name}` but since the site is common to all instances it is the application name below site level I would like to use in the log file path.

Each of the applications are installed from separate baseDirs but I would prefer to have logs in a folder structure away from the baseDir.

Any hints to getting the application name? When searching for answers most threads leads to HostingEnvironment.SiteName but I have not been able to find similar ways to get the application name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath` property and then hookup an NLog layout renderer.

This should work for NLog 4.4 and newer:

```
LayoutRenderer.Register("iis-application-name", (logEvent) => HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath);
```

Then you can use `${iis-application-name}` in your NLog config file.

Just remember to register the renderer before doing anything else, that is do it before you start loggin.